# C# extends implements and abstract classes

Tags: java, c#

A few days ago, I started "recoding" project from Java into C#.  I encountered a few errors. The "biggest" one that I get the following error:

> does not implement interface member

### C# Code:

```
class Player : Entity
{
    //Main Class
    public void Kill(){ ... }
}

abstract class Entity : MapObject, Killable
{
    //...
}

abstract class MapObject
{
    //...
}

interface Killable
{
    void Kill();
}
```

In my **Java** project, the interface class is abstract, Entity class looks like:

```
abstract class Entity extends MapObject implements Killable {...}
```

And it works... So what is wrong with my C# code ?

Comment: As an aside, the convention is that interfaces are prefixed with `I`, so your `Killable` interface in idiomatic C# would be named `IKillable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define method `Kill()` in `Entity` class.
If you don't need implementation of this method in abstract class, the method `Kill()` in `Entity` should be `abstract`:

```
abstract class Entity : MapObject, Killable
{
    public abstract void Kill(); // or without "abstract" if method needs a body
}
```